# Two connected tables in which same record has same Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a SQL table Users with some users with PK's. I need to create second table UserInfo with same users from table Users. I am connect these tables with FK's. The difficulty is that I need to both table's users have SAME PRIMARY KEY. Like User "Peter" with (UserId 5) MUST have (UserInfoId 5) in UserInfo table . Is that possible and if it is, how can i do that?

Comment: It sounds like this is a one-to-one relationship and you want to enforce that there always be a corresponding record in both tables.  

Since inserting into one table will be atomic, I don't think you can enforce a circular PK-FK-PK scenario.

If the table is not too wide, then add the fields to the base table.  If you need a separate table because it's physically too wide; then you could refactor the optional/nullable fields to the second table and keep the required/ non-nullable fields in the base table.

Answer (score 1):

Either there is a **one to one relationship** between `Users` and `UserInfo`, in that case `UserInfo.UserID` is PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY at the same time.

```
CREATE TABLE UserInfo (
    UserID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Info varchar(max),
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserInfo_User FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

OR

You have a **one to many relationship** between `Users` and `UserInfo`, in that case `UserInfo.UserID` is  a FOREIGN KEY and you need a separate PRIMARY KEY `UserInfo.UserInfoID`.

```
CREATE TABLE UserInfo (
    UserInfoID int  PRIMARY KEY,
    UserID int NOT NULL,
    Info varchar(max),
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserInfo_User FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```